# How to iterate eml file with mailutils?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, cat, mailutils, mbox

How would a directory of `.eml` files be iterated?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ mail -f foomail/foo.eml 
"/home/nicholas/foomail/foo.eml": 0 messages
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Whereas, I'd like to see a list to select from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, EML format is **not** one of the supported [local mailbox formats](https://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html#Local-Mailboxes) by GNU Mailutils ... But, apparently the MBOX format is.

Luckily the [conversion from EML to MBOX](https://askubuntu.com/a/1493439/968501) is easy and that's what you probably should consider.

To demonstrate that, I used this [sample EML](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FlexConfirmMail/Thunderbird/master/sample.eml) ... so,

```
$ head *.eml
==> 1.eml <==
FCC: imap://piro-test@mail.clear-code.com/Sent
X-Identity-Key: id1
X-Account-Key: account1
From: "piro-test@clear-code.com" <piro-test@clear-code.com>
Subject: test confirmation
To: piro.outsider.reflex+1@gmail.com, piro.outsider.reflex+2@gmail.com,
 mailmaster@example.com, mailmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.com,
 webmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.jp, mailmaster@example.jp
Message-ID: <05c18622-f2ad-cb77-2ce9-a0bbfc7d7ad0@clear-code.com>
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 14:54:37 +0900

==> 2.eml <==
FCC: imap://piro-test@mail.clear-code.com/Sent
X-Identity-Key: id1
X-Account-Key: account1
From: "piro-test@clear-code.com" <piro-test@clear-code.com>
Subject: test confirmation
To: piro.outsider.reflex+1@gmail.com, piro.outsider.reflex+2@gmail.com,
 mailmaster@example.com, mailmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.com,
 webmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.jp, mailmaster@example.jp
Message-ID: <05c18622-f2ad-cb77-2ce9-a0bbfc7d7ad0@clear-code.com>
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 14:54:37 +0900

==> 3.eml <==
FCC: imap://piro-test@mail.clear-code.com/Sent
X-Identity-Key: id1
X-Account-Key: account1
From: "piro-test@clear-code.com" <piro-test@clear-code.com>
Subject: test confirmation
To: piro.outsider.reflex+1@gmail.com, piro.outsider.reflex+2@gmail.com,
 mailmaster@example.com, mailmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.com,
 webmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.jp, mailmaster@example.jp
Message-ID: <05c18622-f2ad-cb77-2ce9-a0bbfc7d7ad0@clear-code.com>
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 14:54:37 +0900
```

... and try to read them with `mailutils` (***Doesn't Work***):

```
$ mail -V
mail (GNU Mailutils) 3.16
Copyright (C) 2007-2023 Free Software Foundation, inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$
$ 
$ mail --file *.eml
mail: -f requires at most one command line argument
$ 
$ 
$ mail --file 1.eml
"/home/ubuntu/test/dir/1.eml": 0 messages
```

... Now let's convert those 3 EML messages to one MBOX file:

```
$ for e in *.eml
  do
    date +"From - %a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y" >> file.mbox
    cat "$e" >> file.mbox
    echo >> file.mbox
    done
$ 
$ 
$ ls -lh
total 20K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2.5K Nov 30 17:48 1.eml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2.5K Nov 30 17:48 2.eml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2.5K Nov 30 17:48 3.eml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 7.6K Nov 30 17:49 file.mbox
$ 
$ 
$ head file.mbox 
From - Thu Nov 30 17:49:34 2023
FCC: imap://piro-test@mail.clear-code.com/Sent
X-Identity-Key: id1
X-Account-Key: account1
From: "piro-test@clear-code.com" <piro-test@clear-code.com>
Subject: test confirmation
To: piro.outsider.reflex+1@gmail.com, piro.outsider.reflex+2@gmail.com,
 mailmaster@example.com, mailmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.com,
 webmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.jp, mailmaster@example.jp
Message-ID: <05c18622-f2ad-cb77-2ce9-a0bbfc7d7ad0@clear-code.com>
```

... and try to read it:

```
$ mail --file file.mbox 
"/home/ubuntu/test/dir/file.mbox": 3 messages 3 new
>N   1 piro-test@clear-co Thu Nov 30 17:49  64/2549  test confirmation
 N   2 piro-test@clear-co Thu Nov 30 17:49  64/2549  test confirmation
 N   3 piro-test@clear-co Thu Nov 30 17:49  64/2549  test confirmation
? 
FCC: imap://piro-test@mail.clear-code.com/Sent
X-Identity-Key: id1
X-Account-Key: account1
From: "piro-test@clear-code.com" <piro-test@clear-code.com>
Subject: test confirmation
To: piro.outsider.reflex+1@gmail.com, piro.outsider.reflex+2@gmail.com,
 mailmaster@example.com, mailmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.com,
 webmaster@example.org, webmaster@example.jp, mailmaster@example.jp
Message-ID: <05c18622-f2ad-cb77-2ce9-a0bbfc7d7ad0@clear-code.com>
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 14:54:37 +0900
X-Mozilla-Draft-Info: internal/draft; vcard=0; receipt=0; DSN=0; uuencode=0;
 attachmentreminder=0; deliveryformat=4
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/69.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="------------26A45336F6C6196BD8BBA2A2"
Content-Language: en-US

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------26A45336F6C6196BD8BBA2A2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
? q
Held 3 messages in /home/ubuntu/test/dir/file.mbox
```

... and it works.