# How to import an mbox file into the Pine or Alpine mail client?

Tags: command-line, email, text-processing, mailutils, mbox

I'm a light Alpine e-mail client user.

If I navigate into ~/mail and run `mail -f baz` I'll get an [expected](https://superuser.com/q/1818396/977796) list of old alpine/pine messages.

Alpine doesn't use `mbox`.

I added an mbox backup to that directory.  When launching Pine I certainly can see that `mbox`.

From the Pine mail client I can see a list of mail directories:

```
  ALPINE 2.25   FOLDER LIST                                                                           Folder: INBOX                                                                           No Messages  

INBOX               sent-mail           saved-messages      22aug_saved         foo.mbox            foobar              sent-mail-aug-2022  sent-mail-dec-2022  sent-mail-may-2022  sent-mail-nov-2022
sent-mail-oct-2022  sent-mail-sep-2022
```

There's the `foo.mbox` as expected.  But, because it's `mbox`, and not whatever Pine will normally use, it just opens as one massive email.

How can I open this mbox file from Pine properly?

new information:

I [downloaded](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qsnake/git/master/t/t5100/sample.mbox) a sample `mbox` file and imported it to Alpine fine, as described by the solution from the new user.  So it's something about the Thunderbird `mbox` file which is wonky.  No doubt PEBKAC of some variety.  I'll ask a new question.

Comment: Your pine seems to be configured to use Maildir format and not mbox format. I haven't used pine for a long time, so I don't remember if there is a specific key combination or command line switch that allows you to read in a mbox file if the default is Maildir. Maybe you can find something in the documentation.

Comment: that's exactly what I was thinking!  I just didn't have the right terminology.  Thanks.

Comment: the deleted answer with three downvotes from a new user is, so far as I know, correct.  It's not working for some unknown reason.  I'd remind everyone to be kind to new users.

I hope that the answer gets added back as it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

This almost works for me:

Locate Your Alpine Configuration:
First, make sure Alpine is installed on your system.
Find the directory where Alpine stores its mail configuration. This is typically located in your home directory and might be named .alpine or .pine.

Place Mbox File in Mail Directory:
Copy or move your mbox file into the Alpine mail directory.
You may need to create a new folder within the mail directory to organize the imported messages.

Launch Alpine:
Open the Alpine mail client. You can do this by typing alpine in the terminal and pressing Enter.

Access Folder List:
Once in Alpine, press M to access the main menu.
Select "Folder List" from the menu.

Subscribe to New Folder:
If you created a new folder for your Mbox file, you may need to subscribe to it.
Press L for "Folder List" and then S to subscribe to a new folder.
Choose the folder you created for the mbox file.

Check Imported Mail:
Navigate back to the main menu (M) and select the folder where you placed the mbox file.
Alpine should recognize the Mbox file, and you should see the imported emails.

for conversion of MBOX use this MBOX suite https://www.softaken.com/mbox-suite

as a general solution, that should work.  Or so I understand.  It's not working for the mbox file which I've downloaded from Thunderbird for unknown reasons.  I'm trying to validate the mbox, or find a sample to [validate](https://askubuntu.com/q/92082/847449).

I'm adding this as an answer because it's the general solution so far as I'm aware and therefore useful, as well as being fairly detailed.

Comment: It is possible that it's not working for imported mbox file because (as I just checked) mbox files created by Alpine have by default one "fake" email message at the beginning that contains a warning to not delete it and an info that it is needed for Alpine to function properly. Maybe if you manually, using a text editor, copy & paste that fake email from one of Alpine-created mail files to the imported one, it will be recognized.

Comment: yeah, but I couldn't get mailutils to open the Thunderbird mbox file with the "mail" command.  the "mail" command opens the Alpine created, and sample, mbox files fine.  It's just when I create them through Thunderbird.

Comment: Don't use any special utilities. Try to open both files (created by Alpine and imported from Thunderbird) in a simple, plain text editor and try to spot any differences.